# How to extract and encode data of text file in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, decode, encode

I know it's been asked a lot and I tried some things but I can't make it right:

I have a text file like this:

```
From: VENCA <email@infoclientes.venca.es>
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=BFMaxi,_midi_o_mini=3F_=A1No_pases_d?=
 =?ISO-8859-1?Q?e_largo_porque_esto_te_interesa!?=
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Lo_mejor_de_Gmail_est=C3=A9s_donde_est=C3=A9s?=
From: Equipo de Gmail <mail-noreply@google.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Tres_consejos_para_sacarle_el_m=C3=A1ximo_partido_a_Gmai?=
From: Equipo de Gmail <mail-noreply@google.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Organ=C3=ADzate_mejor_con_la_bandeja_de_entrada_de_Gmail?=
From: Equipo de Gmail <mail-noreply@google.com>
From: VENCA <email@infoclientes.venca.es>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?MARINA,_comprueba_que_tus_datos_se?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?an_correctos_y_=C2=A1bienvenid@_a_Venca!?=
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Nuevo_inicio_de_sesi=C3=B3n_en_Chrome_con_Windows?=
From: Google <no-reply@accounts.google.com> 
[...]
```

Each pair of From/Subject or Subject/From is what I want to extract, in the format:

```
From: VENCA <email@infoclientes.venca.es> - Subject: ¿Maxi, midi o mini? ¡No pases de largo porque esto te interesa!
```

[...]

So I have to extract each pair (having in mind that some subjects are 2,3... lines length) gave the format that I want and encode the subject from utf-8, iso... whatever to make them understable

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('infile.txt') as infile:
    try:
        while True:
            line1 = next(infile).rstrip()
            line2 = next(infile).rstrip()

            if line2.startswith('From:'):
                line1, line2 = line2, line1

            print line1, '-', line2

    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks :) but it already "fails" in the first subject since its 2 lines length; giving in the first line from - subject, and in the second one =?ISO... - Subject

Comment: @JoelSánchezLópez Sure, but I imagine you are willing to try to fix that small issue!  Or did you want us to write all the code for you?

Comment: that's what was my first problem at all xD didn't know how to recognize if the subject was 1 or X lines length, and knowing that, how to put all them together and encoded to be understable without "iso" or "utf"... sry if I didn't explained myself well enough :( of course I don't expect to have all the code, but I keep trying many things and any are working very well